# sql: selecting nth place (when multiple rows ar in nth palce)

Tags: sql, max

Given the table:
Products(id, price)

How do I write a sql query to return all the productus with the Nth highest price (can be more than one with that proce)

Thanks

Comment: What RDBMS and version please? Quite important to know which SQL dialect to use...

Comment: What version or flavor of "SQL" are you using? Each implementation has its own tricks...

Comment: @gbn, is this where we say "jinx"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most generic I can make this, but it still uses TOP where some RDBMS use LIMIT, so you may need to make  slight modificiation.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Products
WHERE
  price = (
           SELECT
             MIN(price)
           FROM
             (
              SELECT TOP 9 price FROM Products GROUP BY price ORDER BY price DESC
             )
             AS top_9
          )
```

Other dialects that allow row_number would likely make better options than my nested sub-queries.

**EDIT** : Typed MAX, meant MIN

**EDIT** : Someone suggested I give an example using windowing functions...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY price) AS ranked_position,
    *
  FROM
    Products
)
  AS ranked_products
WHERE
  ranked_position = 9
```

Or use DENSE_RANK, depending on the behavior you want.

Note : Check your RDBMS for use of windowed functions.  Not all are created equal.

Comment: I think it's better to use select "distinct" top 9, otherwise you won't know what's coming back. right?

Comment: Using `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` in this example will give identical results.  But, in my experience, `GROUP BY` is never slower than `DISTINCT`, but sometimes can be faster (RDBMS dependent).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which sql platform you are using, but I would say get the nth row (implementation of this varies based on sql platform) from

```
SELECT DISTINCT price FROM myDB.myTable ORDER BY price DESC;
```

Use the results of this to join on your initial table based on the price.

Comment: That gives a list of all distinct prices, but gives no mechanism for identifying the 9th value by order.

Comment: Correct. Like I said, without knowing which SQL platform this is being run on I cannot specify which way to find the nth row as the implementations of this vary so greatly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT price, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY price DESC) AS priceN FROM myDB.myTable) X 
    WHERE priceN=3
```

formatted code... new to this.

How to check for a tie...editing based on comment...

```
    SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT price,COUNT(price) AS PriceCount, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY price DESC) AS priceN FROM myDB.myTable GROUP BY PRICE HAVING COUNT(price) > 1) X 
    WHERE priceN=3
```

Sorry you have to scroll.  I am getting used to the formatting here.

Comment: the order by in the inside query shouldn't be there.  But it certainly should be in the ROW_NUMBER function call

Comment: As formed, this will give a single item that is 3rd highest priced.  The OP, however, asked for all items of the same price if there is a 'tie'.